# why my getInitialState Fuction not working?

Tags: reactjs

i am using plunker editor for react for learning.
I am at beginner stage and trying to work on states with react for which i write this codes but it is not rendering can you help me through please.

```
var Product = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return(qty=>0);
  },
  buy: function(){
    this.setState({qty:this.state.qty+1});  
  },
  render:function(){
    return (
      <div>
      <p>Android-Rs.1990</p>
      <button onClick={this.buy}>Buy</button>
      <h3>Qty:{this.state.qty}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.render(<Product/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: `getInitialState` expects you to return an object. e.g. `return { qty: 0 };` You are now returning a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `return(qty=>0);` use `return({qty: 0});`

The reason for this is that `getInitialState` requires an object to be returned but in JavaScript `qty=>0` actually creates an anonymous function and would somewhat equal `function(qty) { return 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

What is this? `return(qty=>0);`

Do you want to return a boolean? Use `>=` instead.

If you want to assign the initial value of the state you can just use at the beggining of your component

`state={
   qty:0,
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You should return an object with `quantity` set as 0 as explained here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#setting-the-initial-state

So something like this:

```
  getInitialState: function(){
    return { quantity: 0 };
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

getInitialState should return an object,

```
getInitialState: function(){
return{qty: 0};
```

},